# How do I make a function that slices an array depending on parameters

Tags: python, numpy

So let's say I have a `2x2x2x2x2` numpy array `G`. I want to create a function that slices depending on the parameters `a` and `b` (where `a` and `b` are indices).

For example, I want the function to return `G[0,:,0,:,:]` if `a=0` and `b=2`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a list of slices:

```
idx = [0 if i in axes else slice(None) for i in range(G.ndim)]
```

and then return `G[idx]`:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2015)

def getslice(G, axes):
    idx = [0 if i in axes else slice(None) for i in range(G.ndim)]
    return G[idx]

G = np.random.randint(10, size=(2,2,2,2,2,))
assert np.allclose(getslice(G, [0,2]), G[0,:,0,:,:])
```

Comment: This one occurred to me too, but surely there must be something more numpythonic ??

Comment: What does slice(None) mean.

Comment: @Glassjawed: [slice objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) can be used to index sequence (such as arrays). `x[slice(None)]` is equivalent to `x[:]`, except that `slice(None)` is an object whereas `:` is not.

Comment: @wim: This kind of construction is used in the [NumPy code base](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/arraypad.py#L167) itself. So if I missed something, I feel at least I'm in good company.

Comment: fair enough, I thought there must be some way with some methods G.take or G.compress or other .. but I couldn't figure it out either.  have a +1 !

Answer (score 1):

I would think [`@unutbu's slice based method`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33313863/3293881) to be the go-to approach for being short and low on memory usage. Alternatively, I would like to propose an approach based on [`transposing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) and [`reshaping`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), like so -

```
# Get axes IDs for remaining axes
o_axes = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(G.ndim),axes)

# Transpose multi-dimensional array such that input axes are brough at th front
sliced_arr = G.transpose(np.concatenate((axes,o_axes)))

# Finally reshape to merge axes into one axis & slice to get first index from it
out = sliced_arr.reshape(np.append(-1,np.array(G.shape)[o_axes]))[0]
```

Verify output -

```
In [23]: G = np.random.randint(0,9,(5,2,4,3,6,4,2))
    ...: axes = [0,2,5]
    ...: out_direct = G[0,:,0,:,:,0,:]
    ...: 

In [24]: o_axes = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(G.ndim),axes)
    ...: sliced_arr = G.transpose(np.concatenate((axes,o_axes)))
    ...: out = sliced_arr.reshape(np.append(-1,np.array(G.shape)[o_axes]))[0]
    ...: 

In [25]: np.allclose(out_direct,out)
Out[25]: True
```